# Stitch 360 fisheye video with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fisheye

I have **dual-fisheye** MP4 files generated from a Rylo camera.  Using FFmpeg on Windows, I want to convert the video into **equirectangular** format.

The command I have been trying is:

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i input.mp4 -vf v360=dfisheye:e:ih_fov=208:iv_fov=208 -y output.mp4
```

The the catch is that the input fisheye video is rotated 90° like this:

[image]

Which is generating equirectangular output like below, but the fisheye video needs to be rotated first.

[image]

I've experimented with some of the command line switches like `pitch, yaw, out_forder=brludf, and out_frot=222222` and none seem to make a difference.  Can someone explain the command line parameter that will rotate the input video before stitching it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `roll`?

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i input.mp4 -vf v360=dfisheye:e:ih_fov=208:iv_fov=208:roll=-90 -y output.mp4
```

Link to the documentation:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360

Comment: `roll=-90` does the trick for me. It properly rotates both of the fisheye images. Next I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the lens radius and Nadir radius factors like I've seen in the ***Shotcut*** app that is based on FFmpeg.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to that but ffmpeg does have options to change the radius and center of both the fisheye.
Section 2.55 of the book: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/ffmpeg/FFmpeg_Book.pdf